# angular js route not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have following code.All I am trying is to make a simple login and dashboard app. after successful login the user can see dashboard for that I have two routes login and dashboard initially login route is default once login is successful then I want to route to dashboard route and the respective template and controller should get loaded but somehow that does not work. I need help to figure out what is wrong

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="salesApp">
<body ng-controller="loginController">
    <form name="loginForm">
        <!--login form-->
    </form>
    <script src="./js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/app/salesApp.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/controller/loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/services/communicationService.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

loginController.js

```
app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http, communicationService, $location){
    $scope.isLoginFailed = false;
    $scope.login= function(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/login?username=" + $scope.user.username + "&password=" + $scope.user.password)
        .success(function(response){
            if(response.sessionId && response.loginSucceeded){
                $location.path("/login");
            }else{
                $scope.isLoginFailed = true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

salesApp.js

```
 var app = angular.module("salesApp", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            debugger;
            $routeProvider.
                when('/login', {
                    templateUrl: '../../login.html',
                    controller: 'loginController'
                }).
                when('/dashboard', {
                    templateUrl: '../../dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'dashBoardController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/login'
                });
        }]);

app.controller('dashBoardController', function($scope, $http, communicationService){
    $scope.sessionData = communicationService.getSessionData();
    $scope.isValidSession - $scope.sessionData.sessionId !== null ? true : false;
    $scope.isValidSession = $scope.isValidSession && $scope.sessionData.loginSucceeded;
});
```

dashboard.html

```
<html ng-app="salesApp">
<head>
</head>
<div ng-view ng-controller="dashBoardController">
<h1>
demo
</h1>
</body>
```

but neither login nor dashboard route gets fired, Can any one help me to find out what wrong am I doing

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to repeat angular `ng-app` and `ng-view ng-controller="dashBoardController"` directives in partial templates. Change `dashboard.html` like this:

```
<h1>demo</h1>
```

However in `index.html` you have to put `ngView` somewhere. It will be filled with loaded templates:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Check the demo with fixed code:

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Is3oXmkcRvDYkiAuvnCF?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot. but still i am having one doubt if i put ng-view to body along with ng-controller the console floods with error. can you explain why is that. but if I put ng-view to div in body it works fine

Comment: You can only have one ngView directive on the page. Nested views can't have inner ngView's.